# Ansible : pass a variable in a json_query filter

Tags: json, ansible

I need to pass a variable in a json_query filter.

This example, with a fixed string, is working correctly (string=tutu) :

```
- set_fact:
 my_value_exist: "{{ my_json.json | json_query('contains(component.name,`tutu`)')}}"
```

But i need to pass a variable , instead of tutu

```
- set_fact:
 my_value_exist: "{{ my_json.json | json_query('contains(component.name,`{{my_var}}`)')}}"
```

{{my_var}} is a string retreived in a previous step

Do you have the correct syntax, so that the variable {{my_var}} could be passed correctly in parameter ?

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Comment: can you try this: `my_value_exist: "{{ my_json.json | json_query('contains(component.name,`my_var`)')}}"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: the value exist in the json, but with this syntax the returned value is equal to false.

my_value_exit should return true

Answer (score 11):

Use helper variable for a task:

```
- set_fact:
    my_value_exist: "{{ my_json.json | json_query(qry) }}"
  vars:
    qry: 'contains(component.name,`{{my_var}}`'
```

Comment: I found a solution with this task :

Comment: - name: Does my value exists
  debug: var=item
  with_items: "{{ my_json.json | json_query(my_query)}}"
  vars:
    my_query: "contains(component.name,{{ my_var | to_json | replace ('\"',\"'\")}})"
  register: my_value_exist

Comment: Post it as separate answer, please. But it's an overkill in my opinion.

Comment: helped me when trying to use a variable with json_query. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to avoid using a helper var you can use the second var directly by wrapping it in escaped double quotes ( `\"` ) between plus characters ( `+` ) like this:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    my_value_exist: "{{ my_json.json | json_query('contains(component.name,`\" + my_var + \"`)') }}"
```

I know that this is a old question but it might help someone since this is the top result on the subject on google.