# How I can use Variables in Ansible json_query?

Tags: ansible, json-query

I want to use a ansible variable inside the json query filter.
This is my Code:

Playbook execution:

```
ansible-playbook debug.yml -e "project_environment=live"
```

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ project_environment }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ check_objects | json_query('`{{project_environment}}`.current') }}"
```

This is my dictionary:

```yaml
check_objects:
  live:
    current:
    - example.com
    next:
    - next.example.com
```

This is what i got:

```
TASK [debug : debug] 
ok: [sample-hostname] => {
    "msg": "live"
}

TASK [debug  : debug]
ok: [sample-hostname] => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

**When i replace the variable by using the expected value, the output it is working fine:**

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ check_objects | json_query('live.current') }}"
```

```
TASK [typo3-deployment/check : debug] 
ok: [sample-hostname] => {
    "msg": [
        "example.com"
    ]
}
```

I think it runs in trouble while interpolate the variable.

I have tried this solution but it doesn't work too: [Ansible : pass a variable in a json_query filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038985/ansible-pass-a-variable-in-a-json-query-filter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The task with json_query below

```
  vars:
    project_environment: live
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ check_objects|
                 dict2items|
                 json_query(query)|
                 flatten }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?key=='{{ project_environment }}'].value.current"
```

gives

```
"msg": [
    "example.com"
]
```

The same result can be achieved also with the task

```
- debug:
    var: check_objects[project_environment].current
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'm not sure about if i can use multiple variables in the query..
This is not working for me:
Example: [?key=='{{ project_environment }}'].[?value=='{{ project_status }}']

Comment: Hi @bswe

" {{ check_objects | json_query(\"[?key=='\"+project_environment+\"'].value.current\") }}"

Should work

Answer (score 1):

For two variables this works fine for me.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ check_objects | json_query(query) }}"
  vars:
    query: "{{ project_environment }}.{{ project_status}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I came here because I had a similar issue (although with a different query plugin). Hopefully this solution will help people who search for it.
See my playbook for example. Text which is commented out is the one that doesn't work, while the one not commented works just fine

```
- name: get vlan
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    token: "mytoken"
    url: https://example.com
    group: vlan_group
  tasks:
    - name: Obtain vlans
      set_fact:
        #vlans: "{{ query('networktocode.nautobot.lookup', 'vlans', api_filter='status=active group={{ group }}', api_endpoint={{ url }}, api_version='1.3', token= {{ token }}, validate_certs=False) }}"
        vlans: "{{ query('networktocode.nautobot.lookup', 'vlans', api_filter='status=active group=\"' + group + '\"', api_endpoint=vars['url'], api_version='1.3', token=vars['token'], validate_certs=False) }}"
```

Inside string `\"' + variable_name + '\"` worked, while if I want to perform whole variable substitution, then I had to use `vars['variable_name']`

Comment: Dude you just made my day. Thanks a bunch, you're awesome. Ansible/Jinja escaping sometimes really is just braindamaged... :D

Answer (score 1):

A solution that worked when I needed to use a variable inside a jsonquery filter. I could not get any of the solutions mentioned to work, except the below:

```
 - name: Package the we are looking for
  debug:
    var: final_package

- name: Get final link and sha for package
  set_fact:
    sentinel_link: "{{ json_data | json_query('data[?fileName==`' + final_package + '`].link') | first }}"
```

Backticks around the quotations are important or it will fail